# Do variables passed into functions accepting the base class still retain their most derived class?

Tags: c++, class, function, inheritance

For instance, consider:

```
class Deriv : public Base {...};
...
bar(Deriv d);
bar(Base b);
foo(Base b) {bar(b);}
...
Deriv x;
foo(x); // does x get treated as Base for the bar() call
        // or retain its Deriv type?
```

And also what if `foo` passes by reference?

Comment: Highly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c

Comment: If you're just concerned about function calls, make sure the appropriate methods are marked virtual and you should be good to go

Comment: Thanks - does the slicing problem also affect variables passed by reference?

Comment: Slicing affects pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference.

Comment: Specifically [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/274636/902497) discusses slicing as part of parameter passing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're passing by value, hence you're creating a new object of type Base and doing a copy assign to it..

Very bad, you'll experience slicing..it will not retain it's stage an not suggested.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing

Either pass by reference or const reference which is anyhow better and quicker:

```
bar(const Base& b)
```

or pass a pointer to the object and you'll retain the state.
    bar(Base* b);

That would be the correct way to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `x` will be a `Base`, this is because you are creating a new `Base` object when you call the function.  That is, on the function call, the constructor for `Base` is called, creating a `Base` `b` copied from the argument's (`x`'s) `Base` subobject (known as object slicing).  It's not being *treated* as a `Base`, it creates a new `Base`

If you, however, take the argument as a `Base &`, it will be treated as a `Derived`, consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
class Base {
    public:
        virtual void func() const {
            std::cout << "Base::Func()" << std::endl;
        }

};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
        virtual void func() const {
            std::cout << "Derived::Func()" << std::endl;
        }
};

int do_func_value(Base b){
    b.func(); // will call Base::func
}

int do_func_ref(const Base & b){
    b.func(); // will call whatever b's actual type is ::func
}

int main(void){
    Derived d;
    do_func_value(d);
    do_func_ref(d);
    return 0;
}
```

this outputs:

```
Base::Func()
Derived::Func()
```